# C++ Program execution halts with no error

Tags: c++, stack

I've started to experiment (no previous experience with the language) with c++, I'm using Dev C++ ver. 5.11.
I'm trying to implement a stack, I don't want to use the ready Stack library because I want to practice.
However with no errors the program halts after printing out the stack items and further statements aren't executed.
What is going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *push(struct node *root, int ikey){
    struct node *ptr;
    
    ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data=ikey;
    ptr->next=root;
    root = ptr;
    return root;
}
struct node *pop(struct node *root){
    struct node *ptr;
    
    ptr = root;
    root = ptr->next;
    return root;
}
void Print_Stack(struct node *root){
    struct node *n;
    n = root;
    do{
        printf("Node -> %d \n",n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }while (n != NULL);

}

int main(){
    struct node *stoiva, *tmp;
    int x;
    tmp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    do{
        printf("Give x :");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if (x > 0){
            stoiva = push(stoiva, x);
        }
    }while ( x > 0);
    tmp = stoiva;
    do{
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }while (tmp->next != NULL);
    printf ("-----------------\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does your debugger say anything?

Comment: In `main` the variable `stoiva` is uninitialized. Imagine what that does for the end of your list. Also, you're leaking memory; `tmp` in `main` is near pointless. And, you should be using `new` and `delete` (and ideally, smart pointers and/or `std::list`, but I realize this is academic).

Comment: Your style is very C-like, so you are really practicing C, not so much C++. Nothing wrong with that, of course.

Comment: If you really want to practice, then practice C++, don't write C code. Forget `malloc` and `NULL`, and `#include<stdio.h>` and `#include<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: this doesnt look like c++. In c++ you do not need to deal with manual memory managment via raw pointer, `malloc` is almost always wrong, the headers are `cstdio` and `cstdlib`, `using namespace std;` is totally unnecessary in this code, `NULL` should not be used anymore, `struct node *stoiva, *tmp;` is a c-ism in c++ you can write `node* stoiva; node* tmp;`, and there is more.... better use a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn c++

Comment: Look for the place where you set the `next` pointer of the last node to the null pointer. (Related: don't leave your variables uninitialized.)

Comment: fwiw, using the standard library does require practice too. Its your choice to learn about writing your own datastructure or learn about writing c++ code. What you are doing now it not practicing c++. "I am not using the standard library because I want to practice" is a misunderstanding to some extend

Comment: Apologies I was meaning not use the "Stack" Library provided by C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues:

```
    do{
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }while (tmp->next != NULL);
```

will crash if `tmp` is initially null (an empty stack) and will also fail to print the last element in the stack. Both problems can be solved with:

```
    while (tmp){
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

`stoiva` is not initialised so may not be null, you should always initialise pointers for safety.

You should use `new` rather than `malloc` in c++, not only is it required for a lot of c++ types its much simpler too:

```
ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))
```

becomes:

```
ptr=new node();
```

You should check the result of `scanf` to make sure it succeeded before using the resulting value.

You need to free the memory you allocated, in your case you need to use `free` but if using `new` you need to use `delete`.

A fully working version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *next = nullptr;
};

node *push(node *root, int ikey){
    node *ptr = new node();
    ptr->data = ikey;
    ptr->next=root;
    root = ptr;
    return root;
}

node *pop(node *root){
    node *ptr = root;
    root = ptr->next;
    delete ptr;
    return root;
}

int main(){
    node *stoiva = nullptr;
    int x;
    do{
        printf("Give x :\n");
        if (scanf("%d",&x) != 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (x > 0){
            stoiva = push(stoiva, x);
        }
    }while ( x > 0);
    node * tmp = stoiva;
    while (tmp){
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    while (stoiva){
        stoiva = pop(stoiva);
    }
    printf ("-----------------\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Your input was really useful and much appreciated. Now I understand better C++ :)

Comment: @Nik D I'd like to argue that now you understand `C` better. Unfortunately there's tons of material online that teaches a very bad or at least antiquated style of C++. If you really want to learn C++ and not C, I'd strongly advise to recreate your stack code in modern C++.

Comment: I had had to write code in C for more than 20 years. I rediscovered it recently so from 1 of 10 I understood the language I went to 2 of 10. So for me it's a help, of course there is always more to learn about programming :)